# How can I splice together two videos (at times/places/size/space/given coordiates)

Tags: linux, bash, mplayer, mencoder

I'm thinking:

```
some_command -file1 file.flv -appendTo outFile.flv -appendAt 00.00.0 -xy = 0,0 -size=1.0 -TS = 00:00.0  -includeSound
```

where

- outFile.flv - flv file that is appended to
- appendAt - a time stamp at this time the outFile.flv file shall either be grown and appened to or if the file already exists then the new input will replace the old input at the specified coordinates/size/time possibly growing the file in that process
- file [mandatory] - input file, this file is added to the output
- vidXY [mandatory] - the corner of the input file to start diplaying this image is added in to the existing file, the output file may have to grow in time. New areas which are out of bounds of the previous video are clipped.
- includeSound - new sound super imposes old sound or is dropped (if ommitted)
- Size [optional] - the input file can be resized

I was hoping there would be a bash script that could compile that command for something standard like youtube videos.

Comment: are you excluding `ffmpeg` as a possible solution? Good luck.

Comment: anything is valid, I've tried ffmpeg but I don'think it works out of the box right? I need to add a bazillion dependencies (mp3 support etc..),

Comment: Not a video file guru, just learning stuff myself. Did you check out the Qs here (60+) and on SuperUser.com (~14) for `splice video` ? A few look relevant. Good luck.